# How can I change the background color of venn diagram using draw.pairwise.venn in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

draw.pairwise.venn returns an image object, hence can't wrap it with CSS. Is there any way I can change background color of venn diagram.

```
library(VennDiagram)

renderPlot(draw.pairwise.venn(32+134,24+134,134,category = c("A","B"),
                                      ext.text = TRUE,lty = "blank",fill = c("yellow","green"),scaled = FALSE,
                                      ext.pos = 0,cat.pos = 0, cat.dist = 0.06))
```

I am trying to match my plot with the color of my shiny dashboard.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! When posting an R question, make sure to include the libraries you're using if they go beyond the default ones. For example, what library is `draw.pairwise.venn` in?

Comment: It might also be worth checking out a different library - for example, the [`ggvenn`](https://github.com/yanlinlin82/ggvenn) package leverages `ggplot2` syntax so the background color would be easier to change.

Comment: Thank You @krfurlong for informing me about ggvenn, it will solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @krfurlong `ggvenn` package can be used to plot Venn diagrams, and customize your plot according to requirements with the help of `ggplot2`.

you can install ggvenn by:

```
if (!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("yanlinlin82/ggvenn")
```